# Get the sum of total & individual within the group

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the top 2 channels and its video along with their sum of revenue and view.
I also want to sort the results based on top revenue of channels

Input

```
channel_name    video   views   revenue
abc             v1       1       4
abc             v2       1       5
abc             v2       1       5
efg             v3       2       3
ijk             v4       3       2
```

Expected output

[image]

This is what Ib tried so far,

```
select Channel_Name, video ,
       sum(a.`Revenue`), 
       sum(views)
       rank() over ( partition by `Video` ORDER BY sum(revenue)  desc) as ranking
from topchannels 
group by Channel_Name, Video
limit 2;
```

Comment: SQL tables/resultset are orderless by standards using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` to get the "first 2" matching records is pretty much meaningless..

Comment: Hint: First do all the aggregation per group of video in a subquery; then use that subquery's result-set in `FROM` clause to get top 2 videos per channel

Comment: (before somebody post as comment)... but `GROUP BY` implicitly sorts in MySQL...  i can tell you that feature is pretty much deprecated since MySQL 5.7 and [removed](https://mysqlserverteam.com/removal-of-implicit-and-explicit-sorting-for-group-by/) in MySQL 8

Comment: ... @MadhurBhaiya after reviewing the expected results do you think this should be handled by MySQL or the application?  I would say this is a display issue which needs to be handled in the application..

Comment: @RaymondNijland problem statement words require aggregation and ranking; but the same data is insufficient to make any guess

Comment: *"but the same data is insufficient to make any guess "* yea i was more pointing to the "merged" `channel_name = abc` records in the resultset ... @MadhurBhaiya .. topicstarter should really see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

- I think I found a good solution for you.
- Cannot hide    channel name duplicate.
- Hope this helps

  ```
  SELECT chanel_name
       , video
       , sum(views) as views
       , sum(revenue) as revenue 
    FROM teste 
   GROUP 
      BY chanel_name
       , video;
  ```

Result:

```
abc V1 1 4
abc V2 2 10
efg V3 2 3
ijk V4 3 2
```

Comment: distrinct and group  by .. ??   group by don't need  distinct  ..(and is not a function)

Comment: How does that work? As DISTINCT is not a function and would still work on the complete record...  More or less meaning this result is based on luck..  Also this is using GROUP BY invalid a other luck factor but like @scaisEdge said you are using it redundant..

Comment: Sorry, something is wrong, but it gave the expected result

Comment: *"Sorry, something is wrong, but it gave the expected result"* like i said based on luck [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/djGaEVRL8Ec3KZ6WNmdS3Y/0) is what could happen -> *"Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.test.channel_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"*

Comment: I think I understand, Thank you for your help.on my mysql it worked.

Comment: Maybe read -> [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) as that is the way how MySQL should always have handled GROUP BY from the start confirm the ANSI/ISIO SQL standards..

Comment: Nope, Still the Channel name aren't grouped together

Comment: Can't group channel name if you have one more video